# Global settings in a R package

Tags: r, package, settings

I am making a R package, but in order for it to work I need to set some "global" settings.

I could make a package with the settings and require("that package") in each function in the new package. However, this seems like a bad solution to me.

```
 options(scipen=999)
 options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
 Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
```

These are the settings.

I could ofcourse write it on the top of each function. But again, it seems like a bad solution as I want these settings implemented across all functions in the package

Comment: It definitely seems like bad practice to me to not respect users' global settings. Maybe you could say more about why your need such settings, and why global? Could be better ways of accomplishing your goal than messing with global settings

Comment: Makes sense.. i did not see that angle...